# Issue with spaces in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I have created JavaScript code for validation of a simple text field. The issue is when I want to skip spaces in field,

```
var strFilter = /^[A-Za-z]*$/;

var chkVal2 = document.getElementById("fname").value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
if ((!strFilter.test(chkVal2)) || (chkVal2 == "")) {
    alert("Please enter a valid first name\r\n (only characters)");
    document.getElementById("fname").style.background = "#DFE32D";
    document.getElementById("fname").focus();
    document.getElementById("fname").value = null;
    return false;
}
```

Here I want, when the value is checked, it removes all spaces in ID. The script is going well, but it's not removing spaces.

Comment: What do you mean by 'all spaces in ID'? You mean even the space between words?

Comment: In your code, `chkVal2` contains the trimmed string from user input.

Comment: -1 for unclear question. Do you want to use regular expression to remove all spaces in a string? If so please remove unrelated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fName = document.getElementById("fname");
var chkVal2 = fName.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
fName.value =  chkVal2; // TA DA
```

Comment: Ohh you have again taken cleaned value in ID field.. Does it replace the trimmed and spaces from string?

Comment: @RahulSingh just a comment, you can ignore it.